# Python won't properly compare my assigned variables

Tags: python, variables, comparison

Help, I have no idea where I went wrong in my coding and I think that I didn't do something I should have, but everybody I asked says it's a good code. 
I assigned a variable (stats) to be a certain integer (15). 
Then I asked a user to input an integer into another variable (DEX).
The program then will print one of three things depending if the variable is greater, less than, or equal to stats.
Here's the full code for those who want to help:

```
stats = 15
DEX = raw_input(prompt)
if stats > DEX:
    os.system("cls")
    print TITLE
    print "SO YOUR DEX IS %s CORRECT?" %(DEX)
    time.sleep(4)
    thread_2()
elif DEX > stats:
    print "YOU HAVE TOO MUCH DEX!!"
elif DEX = stats:
    print "ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO ADD ALL YOUR STATS TO DEX?"
```

Comment: That can't be your code-- it would have given you a `SyntaxError`.  As an aside, you should consider upgrading to Python 3: this particular comparison would have raised a helpful `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()` message.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make `DEX` an integer by putting it in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
DEX = int(raw_input(prompt))
```

`raw_input` always returns a string object.  Meaning, you are trying to compare strings and integers, which won't work.

Also, regarding your last `elif`, you need to use `==` for comparison tests.  `=` is for variable assignment.

Comment: If Python 2.x does not have any other way of comparing types of different values, it falls back comparing the types lexicographically. The string `int` is less than the string `str`, so any `int` value is less than any `str` value.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator in your last elif rather than the comparison operator. Your last elif should be:

```
elif DEX == stats:
   print "ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO ADD ALL YOUR STATS TO DEX?"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say:

```
DEX = int(raw_input(prompt))
```

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

[`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) converts a number or string `x` to an integer.